# "Works" in Works Cited when there is only one source?

Tags: citations, essay

I am currently writing an essay on *Adventures of Huckleberry Finn* and I only have one source. Do I still call it a "Works Cited" page?

I read this following website, but it didn't seem to help: https://www.ivcc.edu/stylebooks/stylebook4.aspx?id=14586

Comment: Would "Bibliography" work, or do you want some variant of "Works Cited"?

Comment: I think my teacher requires MLA, which I think requires "Work Cited" or some similar variant...

Comment: I'm not familiar with MLA, but as far as I know (based on other style guides) using "Works Cited" is standard no matter how many sources there are. Just a thought, though, perhaps you need to re-evaluate your use of sources: do you need sources at all, and if so, should you have more than one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing much about MLA, in general I highly recommend adding at least two more sources:

- A source about the author, something like:
   http://www.biography.com/people/mark-twain-9512564
- At least one source on the story itself, something like:
   https://www.gilderlehrman.org/history-by-era/literature-and-language-arts/essays/rethinking-huck

This will give insight in the creation and cultural context of the work being discussed, providing more depth for your own interpretation.

Comment: This is only a literary analysis, I'm only using the book.

Comment: @C.Guan - Yeah, I hate these kinds of things. In the real world, you'd probably inline the information about the work you were analyzing in explanatory form, then move on. In academic settings, you need a bibliography for a single source just to prove you know how to make one.

Comment: @KeithS so true!

Answer (score 3):

According to Blakesley & Hoogeveen's W*riting: A Manual for the Digital Age*, you should write "Work Cited" if there's only one source.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it a Work Cited page

Comment: A little more elaboration should be great. Where did you get this information, for example?